# How to run combination of subset with condition in python

Tags: python, subset, combinations, python-itertools

I have a list of list which is in ascending order of each list element len. For example, `[[1], [1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [1,2,3], [1,3,4]]`.

I would like to get all their subset, such as

```
[([1],), ([1, 2],), ([2, 3],), ([3, 4],), ([1, 2, 3],), ([1, 3, 4],), ([1], [1, 2]), ([1], [2, 3]), ([1], [3, 4]), ([1], [1, 2, 3]), ([1], [1, 3, 4]), ([1, 2], [2, 3]), ([1, 2], [3, 4]), ([1, 2], [1, 2, 3]), ([1, 2], [1, 3, 4]), ([2, 3], [3, 4]), ([2, 3], [1, 2, 3]), ([2, 3], [1, 3, 4]), ([3, 4], [1, 2, 3]), ([3, 4], [1, 3, 4]), ([1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4]), ([1], [1, 2], [2, 3]), ([1], [1, 2], [3, 4]), ([1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]), ([1], [1, 2], [1, 3, 4]), ([1], [2, 3], [3, 4]), ([1], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]), ([1], [2, 3], [1, 3, 4]), ([1], [3, 4], [1, 2, 3]), ([1], [3, 4], [1, 3, 4]), ([1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4])]
```

...so i tried

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
cha=[]
end = len([[1], [1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [1,2,3], [1,3,4]])
for i in range(1, end):
    cha.extend(list(combinations([[1], [1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [1,2,3], [1,3,4]],i)))
print(cha)
```

The problem is my list of list has 72 element and it would be 72C1 + 72C2 + ... + 72C25. The performance is bad that it stops when 72C6.

However, there is some condition so that some combination can be skipped, which is when the total number of element in subset is more than 6. Like `([1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2, 3])`. As my list is in len order, when it has `([1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4])`, it can skip computing `([1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [1,2,3])` and `([1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 3, 4])`, and end directly. I assume a lot computation can be reduced and performance can be better.  But how can I achieve this?

There is another condition that no elements in subset appears more than 2 times, such as `([1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 3, 4])` (1 appears for 3 times). But this condition is not that important that violation will be eliminated later part of my code.

I think my question is a bit similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60841790/conditions-on-itertools-combinations-python), I have tried `filter` suggested but `filter` still loop through all `combination` and performance is the same.

Comment: in your expected output there isn't the one with a total of 6 elements: `[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]` please edit the expected list. and a few others are missing as well.

Comment: @GáborFekete I have edited the expected list.

Comment: I've edited my answer. check now.

Answer (score 0):

Edited as your requirement is different.
Here the solution is:

```
l = [[1], [1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [1,2,3], [1,3,4]]
output = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    l1 = l[:i] + l[i+1:]
    for j in range(len(l1)):
        sub = [l[i]]
        for k in range(j+1):
            
            sub.append(l1[k])
        sub = tuple(sub)
        output.append(sub)
output = [tuple(l[0])] + output
print(output)

#output: [(1,), ([1], [1, 2]), ([1], [1, 2], [2, 3]), ([1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]), ([1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 2, 3]), ([1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4]), ([1, 2], [1]), ([1, 2], [1], [2, 3]), ([1, 2], [1], [2, 3], [3, 4]), ([1, 2], [1], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 2, 3]), ([1, 2], [1], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4]), ([2, 3], [1]), ([2, 3], [1], [1, 2]), ([2, 3], [1], [1, 2], [3, 4]), ([2, 3], [1], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2, 3]), ([2, 3], [1], [1, 2], [3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4]), ([3, 4], [1]), ([3, 4], [1], [1, 2]), ([3, 4], [1], [1, 2], [2, 3]), ([3, 4], [1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]), ([3, 4], [1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4]), ([1, 2, 3], [1]), ([1, 2, 3], [1], [1, 2]), ([1, 2, 3], [1], [1, 2], [2, 3]), ([1, 2, 3], [1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]), ([1, 2, 3], [1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 3, 4]), ([1, 3, 4], [1]), ([1, 3, 4], [1], [1, 2]), ([1, 3, 4], [1], [1, 2], [2, 3]), ([1, 3, 4], [1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4]), ([1, 3, 4], [1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 2, 3])]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But your output only can subset with 2 element. I would like to have 1 and more than 2 elements, for example `([1])` and `([1], [2,3], [3,4])`

Comment: @yolopoi I've edited my answer. check now.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `powerset` recipe from `itertools` but used 1 as the starting index so that empty list is not included:

```
import itertools

arr = [[1], [1,2], [2,3], [3,4], [1,2,3], [1,3,4]]
ps = [c for r in range(1,len(arr)+1) for c in itertools.combinations(arr, r) if sum(map(len,c)) < 7]
print(*ps,sep='\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the performance is not imporved. Your solution also loop through all `combinations`. As mentioned there are 72 list in my `arr` and 72C6 gives a large number and thus low performance. Is there a way that can avoid generated all combination and improve performance? Like stop getting subset of index [0, 1, 4] and jump to [0, 2, 3] so that computing [0, 1, 5] can be reduced and thus reduce computation time.

Comment: then I suggest you to use the 'roughly equivalent' part of the `combinations` and put your constraints in there. note that this might be even slower as the `itertools` function are probably implemented using some C code. Some other things to consider is to calculate the combinations once and save it in a variable, this speeds up subsequent calls.